# Communication between js client and asp.net server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, extjs, xmlhttprequest

I write web site in VS 2008. I use extjs for make side with gridView and button. Now I want to send request to server. I add event to click on button:

```
    function getData()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else
        {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "Default.aspx", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("data", "true");
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

And my question is how can I receive this request on server? I found in the Internet that I should to do it like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Headers["data"] != null)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. I don't understand it, if I use JS page doesn't reload, so why I must check it in method page_load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client side:

For sending GET-request use :

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Default.aspx?data=true");
```

Server side:

Use [HttpRequest.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) for getting params.